# Major effects on cells grown with 5% FBS supplemented media instead of 10% FBS?

Tags: cell-culture, growth-media

I maintain a few cell lines in the laboratory (industrial R&D) that I use regularly for experiments. I realized today that the media i prepared for the week on monday was only supplemented with 50 mL of FBS into 1 L of DMEM, instead of the usual 100 mL that i usually do. I was in a hurry and absentmindedly didn't add the second 50 mL autopipettor's worth.

My cells are fine morphologically but I think they're growing a bit slower than usual, my guess is due to the 1/2 concentration of all the FBS growth factors, etc. Are there any other effects that would be pronounced in these?

I understand that it will be apples to oranges to do compare results with these cells to, say, an experiment done with a batch of cells grown in complete (10% FBS supplemented) media.

Answer (score 2):

If you were to run a flow-based viability assay (annexin V, live/dead fixable dyes, 7-AAD) or dual-fluorescence count (like acridine orange/propidium iodide, popular method as of late), you *might* find that more cells are undergoing apoptosis, or an increase in dead cells. I say this because trypan blue often overestimates viability. Your most pronounced effect should simply be a reduction in viable cells or a slower growth curve if you take those data points. Otherwise you'd need to run some test ([fair example](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2212968516300058)).

The problem being, these observations vary wildly based on what cell line you're using, lot-to-lot variability of the serum, and reagent handling. For example, the serum was heat-inactivated improperly, medium was degraded, bad lot of serum, and so forth. So take this as a generalization and a good reason to validate your serum lots.